# Jest test for a copy to clipboard method using react with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to ensure that the right value is copied to the users clipboard when they click a button. This is my copy method. I am using a ref on the input to access the right value.

```
  protected copyToClipboard() {
   console.log("clicked!");
   const text = this.controls.copyData;

   if (!_.isNil(text)) {
     text.current.focus();
     text.current.select();

     document.execCommand("copy");
     this.setState({copied: true});
   }
 }
```

For my test:

```
  test("Ensure right value is copied to clipboard", () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent />);

    const copyButton = wrapper.find(".copyBtn");
    copyButton.simulate("click");

    const copyToClipboardSpy = jest.spyOn(document as any, "execCommand");
    wrapper.update();

    expect(copyToClipboardSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith("copy");
  });
```

The error I receive when I run the test is `TypeError: document.execCommand is not a function` which makes sense, but I am unsure how to approach this.

I am relatively new to testing, just to put that out there. I also have read that I may not be able to access the document.execCommand but have struggled to find a good alternative to hijack the test and access the value being copied. I appreciate any advice that can be given on the matter!

Answer (score 15):

Posting this in case anyone else was in a similar boat. It's doesn't necessarily check the value yet, but one piece I managed was with the `document.execCommand` method.

I set up a mock function above the wrapper:

```
document.execCommand = jest.fn();
```

With this, the test stopped throwing the `TypeError`. Then my expectations included checking for the spy to have been called, expect my copy state to have changed to true, and:

```
expect(document.execCommand).toHaveBeenCalledWith("copy");
```

Test passes! A possible solution for the value is to see if I can "paste" the value and then check it. Will edit this response if/when I can manage that

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to check the copied value?

Comment: Anyone ever get things to work to place assertions on the value of the clipboard copy and/or to be pasted?

Comment: @suzu94, how to check the copied value?

Comment: Well, since you are mocking the ecexCommand("copy") call, the text is not really copied. This just tests that execCommand is called.

Answer (score 6):

When you use `navigator.clipBoard.writeText` instead of using `document.exec("copy")`, you can refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62351935/how-to-mock-navigator-clipboard-writetext-in-jest) for an elegant solution that lets you assert on the content as well.

Answer (score 1):

Being `execCommand` no longer an option as it is deprecated ([see MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand)), you should be using `navigator.clipboard.writeText('your copied data');`.

To mock `navigator.clipboard`, you could do the following:

```
// It's important to keep a copy, so your tests don't bleed
const originalClipboard = navigator.clipboard;

const mockedWriteText = jest.fn();

navigator.clipboard = {
  writeText: mockedWriteText,
};

const copyComponent = await screen.findByTestId('copy-component');
await userEvent.click(copyComponent);

expect(mockedWriteText).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
expect(mockedWriteText).toHaveBeenCalledWith('your copied data');

// Remember to restore the original clipboard
navigator.clipboard = originalClipboard;
jest.resetAllMocks();
```

- You can also do `Object.assignProperty` instead of directly modifying the navigator object.
- This snippet assumes you are using [React Testing Library](https://testing-library.com/) with [User Event](https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/intro).